# How to get list of model objects requested for deletion in admin panel in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have this simple Django app which uses admin panel as a user portal to add and delete model objects.On addition of each model object I am adding a related data file in S3, how can I get the list of objects requested for deletion from the "delete selected" action, so that the particular object's file in S3 can be deleted.
I tried searching for the related function definition in admin.ModelAdmin class but no help.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can override delete action in django admin panel using [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#admin-actions). You should just add your own delete action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `post_delete` signal: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-delete on the model so it will work in admin but also when a record is deleted from any place in app.